# Run NativeProcess from AIR on a *different core* to the AIR application

Tags: air

My application can be fairly CPU-intensive, as can the server I launch from my application using NativeProcess.

The problem is that they're both using the one core. On a quad-core machine, they both slow to a crawl as they're severely limited on their CPU share.

Is there any way to launch a native process on a different core, or in a way that won't result in such a shared, throttled bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

If you already using NativeProcess, you could also set CPU affinity in platform specific way.